# Filtering by Length of Values in Cell using Custom Formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a column D named "body", containing text. I want to filter (show) only values that are greater than 1000 characters, so that rows with small values < 1000 are not shown. How do I address that in the custom formula ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use D2 or D:D as your argument to `LEN`. (This list is non-exhaustive.)

```
=LEN(D2) >= 1000
=LEN(D:D) >= 1000
```

I used `>=` since you said you don't want to show anything less than 1000.